# Get SFML cross-platform typedefs in SWIG

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, swig, sfml

I'm writing an C++ game and I'm connecting it with [Lua](http://www.lua.org/). The tool I chose for this task was [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), since I want to make my game available to be written in python or some other language. I'm also using [SFML 1.6](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) as the API for multimedia access. This game is also intended to be cross-platform compilable. I'm working at the moment with Xubuntu 11.04 for the first try of the project.

I've already wrapped 90%+ of the SFML API in my game, but when I tried to create an new `sf::Color` object in my Lua script (so that I could call an `sf::RenderWindow::Clear(sf::Color)` method), my Lua Script accused that this call ...

```
renderWindow:Clear( sf.Color( 200, 0, 0 ) ) --Fill the screen with the color.
```

... tried to invoke method `sf:Color( Uint8, Uint8, Uint8 )`; This warning alerted me that SWIG could not identify the SFML special typedef integers for cross-platform development that are defined in the `<SFML/Config.hpp>` header file.

Now, in my SWIG `Config.i` file I could simply write ...

```
typedef unsigned char Uint8; //Always correct
typedef unsigned short int Uint16; //Not always true
typedef unsigned int Uint32; //Not always true
```

... and when compiling my project in another platform, I could just write these **typedefs** attending to this new platform, but I found out that c's `limits.h` header file contains some preprocessor **defines** for the size of each type of integer variable.

My main purpose is to create these **typedefs** in my SWIG script without having to worry in which platform (or compiler) I'm compiling my project.

Right now, my `Config.i` SWIG file looks like this:

```
%{
#include <limits.h>
#include <climits.h>
#include <SFML/Config.hpp>
%}

%include <SFML/Config.hpp>
```

And my SWIG command for generating the wrappers is:

```
swig -c++ -lua -I/PathToSFML -I/PathToLimits ./SFML.i
```

I was hoping that SWIG could find the preprocessor defined variables in the `limits.h` file, which is used by `<SFML/Config.hpp>` but I couldn't make this work...

Does anyone have some tips on how to accomplish my goal ( dynamic typedefing for each platform ) or know a way to make swig get the preprocessor variables defined in `limits.h`?

Comment: "The tool I chose for this task was SWIG, since I want to make my game available to be written in python or some other language." I like SWIG, but that's not the right reason to use it. SWIG is going to require special language-specific coding. At least, if you want the binding to actually work somewhat like the language does. There is no such thing as platform-agnostic language binding.

Comment: Oh, I'm aware of that. But SWIG makes the task of porting to another language easier than writing all the bindings in lua with luabind and later rewriting all the wrappers in python with boost, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any types defined in `limits.h` are not standard and probably shouldn't be relied on. If you want cross-platform fixed size integer typedefs, the C++11 standard library provides the `cstdint` header. This header gives you typedefs for signed and unsigned 8, 16, 32, and 64-bit integers: `int32_t`, `uint32_t`, `int8_t`, and so on.

Most standard library implementations provided `cstdint` as an extension before C++11, but if your implementation doesn't have it, Boost also provides it.

Comment: I'm giving the credits for the answer to @dauphic because he gave me the tips that made me get to the real answer. For the "real" answer, please check my answer post. Thanks dauphic.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user [dauphic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214796/dauphic)'s answer, I tried to use `<stdint.h>` in my example, and then I got this error message when running SWIG in my module:

```
/usr/include/stdint.h:44: Error: Syntax error in input(1).
```

Searching on Google resulted to me these two web pages:

- [[Perl] a simple typedef question #1](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.swig/12288)
- [[Perl] a simple typedef question #2](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.swig/12290)

The second one gave me the answer to this.

My final code looks like this right now:

```
%module Config

%include <stdint.i>

//namespace sf // For some reason, not working when the namespace is here...
//{            // Turns out that I don't need the sf anyway...
typedef int8_t Int8;
typedef uint8_t Uint8;

typedef int16_t Int16;
typedef uint16_t Uint16;

typedef uint32_t Int32;
typedef uint32_t Uint32;
//}
```

As you can see it, `%include <stdint.i>` is a pre-defined module in SWIG since version 1.34 (not really sure about the version... read it somewhere and forgot) which is ready to be used.